# Graylog is not recording string values of metadata key

Tags: graylog, gelf

This is my curl command, it send a message to Graylog that I can see on the dashboard:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"short_message":"test", "my_key":"1234" }' http://127.0.0.1:12201/gelf
```

However, should I change the value of `my_key` from **"1234"** to **"TEST1234"** this message is not showing anywhere in the log.

What could be the problem?